# Fat Free Framework routing cannot not differentiate parameters from URI

Tags: php, routes, fat-free-framework

I am trying to create proper routing for all of the Categories, Subcategories and Single Pages.

My problem is that my Subdirectory Route and my Single Page Route are very much identical:

### Routes

```
GET /@category_slug = CategoryController->CategorySlug
GET /@category_slug/@subcategory_slug = CategoryController->SubcategorySlug
GET /@category_slug/@template_slug = SingleProductController->SinglePageSlug
```

The categories controller handles everything that it needs to handle in relation to categories and subcategories, but clearly won't handle anything related to the single pages. What I mean is the route will not differentiate parameters from URI and will not recognise whether it is Subcategory or a Single page.

Here is a sample URI

```
example.com/MainCategory/Subcategory
example.com/MainCategory1/Subcategory1
example.com/MainCategory/SinglePage1
example.com/MainCategory/SsinglePage2
```

Any Idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'd create a route handler that actually knows all sub categories and single pages and just displays the correct one. There's no other way

Comment: I'd thought of this too, but there are over 16 Categories and 35 Subcategories

Comment: Well, either change your url structure for pages or you have to create that route handler. There's no way F3 could help you here I think.

Comment: What I am currently doing is when controller is searching for a subdomain slug in the DB and returns an empty array, as a next step I am calling another class with method that takes 2 parameters category and single page that takes care getting a single page array for me, but not sure if this would be the right way to go about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why the framework cannot differentiate the two routes is the same as for a human. How would you know if `/foo/bar` is a subcategory or a subpage?

So you have to make the distinction clear in your URL structure. This is up to your imagination. Here are a few examples:

ex1:

- `/foo`
- `/foo/bar`
- `/foo/bar/page/baz`

ex2:

- `/cat/foo`
- `/cat/foo/bar`
- `/page/baz`

ex3:

- `/foo`
- `/foo/c/bar`
- `/foo/p/baz`

ex4:

- `/foo`
- `/foo/bar`
- `/foo/baz.html` << here the suffix helps distinguish subcategories from articles

ex5:

- `/foo`
- `/foo/bar`
- `/foo/bar/baz` << here we keep the subcategory level

There's also the solution, as you [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197790/fat-free-framework-routing-cannot-not-differentiate-parameters-from-uri#comment77368679_45197790) yourself, to keep an ambiguous URL structure and have the controller guess if it should display a subcategory or a single page.

```
GET /@category_slug/@slug = CategoryController->GuessSubcategoryOrSinglePage
```

But I wouldn't advise it, for the following reasons:

- maintenance: bad code readability
- performance: one extra useless SQL call for each page display
- SEO: search engines try to guess a lot of things from the directory structure. Here they would fail, exactly as the framework or a human would do.

NB1: my personal preference goes to example #2, because giving each page its own URL makes it possible to have a page belonging to multiples categories without having to deal with [duplicate content](https://moz.com/learn/seo/duplicate-content) issues. Also it makes your life easier when you have to build a page URL (no need to build the categories hierarchy, no matter where you are in the code).

NB2: don't focus too much on crafting "pretty urls" as most end users don't ever care about them.

Comment: thanks for your in-depth answer, I think the NB1 is something that I would stick to also